# Distance converter keeps navigating to PHP page

Tags: javascript, php, function, converters

I'm working on a basic distance converter and clicking the form to submit keeps redirecting to the somephpfile.php (which doesn't exist as this is an exercise) instead of posting the converted number in kilometers (mi > km) to the div "container bottom." Here is what I've got so far, any help would be much appreciated:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Miles to Kilometers Converter</title>

    <!--/ /-------- Normalize CSS --------/ /-->
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/8.0.1/normalize.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!--/ /-------- Google Fonts --------/ /-->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald|PT+Sans&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

    <!--/ /-------- My Styles --------/ /-->
    <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body>

    <h1>Miles to Kilometers Converter</h1>

    <div class="container top">
        <p>Type in a number of miles and click the button to convert the distance to kilometers.</p>

        <form method="post" action="somephpfile.php" id="convert">

            <input type="number" name="distance" id="distance" placeholder="distance">
            <input type="submit" name="convertdist" value="Convert Distance">

        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="container bottom" id="answer">
        <h2 class="invisible">Answer goes here</h2>
    </div>

    <script>
            var miles = parseInt(document.getElementById("distance").value);
            var kilometers = (miles * 1.609344);
            var answer = document.createElement("P");
            answer.innerHTML = `"${miles} miles converts to ${kilometers} kilometers"`;
            document.getElementsByName("convertdist").addEventListener("click", function(event){
                event.preventDefault();
                    document.getElementById("answer").appendChild();
        });


    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You've a submit button, but you don't want to submit the form? Please take a look what you're working with: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<form method="post" action="somephpfile.php" id="convert">
    <input type="number" name="distance" id="distance" placeholder="distance">
    <input type="submit" name="convertdist" value="Convert Distance">
</form>
```

This form will be submitted when you click on the submit button. Make the form as follows.

```
<form id="convert"> <!-- Taken out the attributes method and action -->
    <input type="number" name="distance" id="distance" placeholder="distance">
    <input type="button" name="convertdist" value="Convert Distance" onclick="convert()"> <!-- Changed the button type submit->button -->
</form>
```

For JavaScript, you have to enclose the JS logic in a function or so, and call it during `onclick` of the submit button, like:

```
<script>
function convert(){
    var miles = parseInt(document.getElementById("distance").value);
    var kilometers = (miles * 1.609344);
    var answer = document.createElement("P");
    answer.innerHTML = `"${miles} miles converts to ${kilometers} kilometers"`;
    document.getElementById("answer").appendChild(answer);
}
</script>
```

Things you got wrong are:

- Conversion + Appending the answer should be callable, meaning it should be a function.
- The conversion function should be invoked whenever the button is clicked. So, it should be bound to the `onclick` event of the convert button.
- Any HTML form with a button of type `submit` will be submitted to the target specified by `action` attribute no matter what, unless you block that with `event.preventDefault()` in your JS. You did that, but not where it should have been done.
- The following in your code makes no sense from where you have put it.

```
document.getElementsByName("convertdist").addEventListener("click", function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
        document.getElementById("answer").appendChild();
    });
```

Put the working version [in this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wLdy921o/). Find time to check out.